# Is there anyway to create a specific shape and fill it with a SKTexture?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

More specifically I want to have a shape of a dog and fill it with a random texture or “coat pattern”. But I don’t want to make the texture match the shape of the dog. I’d like to be able to throw a square texture on different shapes of dogs and it just fills it in. Is this possible to do this with a Skshapenode or Skcropnode? Or am I going to have to manually create textures for each size of dog and just put that texture on a SKSpriteNode.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode/1519956-filltexture

Comment: I looked into this and that seems to be what I want to do but my main concern is SKShapenodes can only be circles or rectangles right? Is there anyway to make a custom shape?

Comment: SKShapeNode can be any shape, that is why it takes in a CGPath